# Is there any easy way to get DOM descendants like with the parents() method when using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

`$('something').parents('selectors')` lets me move several levels up the DOM at once, versus `parent()` which unsurprisingly returns the current element's immediate parent. Unfortunately (though logically), `children()` does not operate like `parents()` and instead only returns the element's immediate children, similar to how `parent()` works. I'm sure that I could whip up something that would get all appropriate descendants no matter how deep, but I'm wondering if there already is some relatively simple way to do this. Any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) such as `find('selectors')`

Answer (score 2):

Something like `.find('*')`, or `$('div#foo *')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('something *');
```

… or if you already have a jQuery object:

```
$('*', foo);
```

Comment: And `$("*", foo);` is synonymous with `$(foo).find("*");`

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use descendants?

I think your after something like

```
$('#something').childrens('.selectors');
```

Can you not jsut do:

```
$('#something *');
```

Or have i totally missed the point of your question?